# SWIG R wrapper not setting class properly/Create R object from C memory pointer

Tags: c, r, class, object, swig

I have a SWIG generated R wrapper which contains the following setClass operations:

```
setClass('_p_f_p_struct_parameters_p_struct_chromosome_p_struct_dataSet__double',
        prototype = list(parameterTypes = c('_p_parameters', '_p_chromosome', '_p_dataSet'),
                        returnType = '_p_f_p_struct_parameters_p_struct_chromosome_p_struct_dataSet__double'),
        contains = 'CRoutinePointer')

setClass('_p_f_p_struct_parameters_p_p_struct_chromosome_p_p_struct_chromosome_int_int__void',
        prototype = list(parameterTypes = c('_p_parameters', '_p_p_chromosome', '_p_p_chromosome', '_int', '_int'),
                        returnType = '_p_f_p_struct_parameters_p_p_struct_chromosome_p_p_struct_chromosome_int_int__void'),
        contains = 'CRoutinePointer')
```

These operation do not appear to be behaving as expected. When I call a function with the output being the creation of a `_p_parameters` object (defined above), I get the following error:

```
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “_p_parameters” is not a defined class
```

The setClass therefore seems to be not doing it's thing.

I tried to manually set the _p_parameters class via:

```
p_parameters<-setClass(Class="_p_parameters", representation = representation(ref = "externalptr"))
```

But this does not seem to work as when I try and modify other parameters (or even print parameters via an inbuilt function) the terminal crashes and hangs.

For reference, the final lines in initialiseParameters (the function which initially own _p_parameters) are calling the native C function via `.Call` then assigning the external pointer to a new object of class _p_paramters as follows:

```
 ;ans = .Call('R_swig_initialiseParameters', numInputs, numNodes, numOutputs, arity, as.logical(.copy), PACKAGE='cgp');
  ans <- new("_p_parameters", ref=ans) ;
```

I've read various R doc on new(), setClass, S3/S4 classes but nothing seems to clarify what I'm meant to be doing here.

Any suggestions on where to start or tutorials that would give a good heads up would be most welcome.

Please keep in mind the C code is not mine (but is freely available under GNU), I am not a C programmer and am only weakly-moderately proficient in R. So please be gentle :)

Cheers.

PS: If I call the function in R terminal via .Call it works as expected (so it doesn't seem to e a C function error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I should post the solution I have to this. The least I could do for a 'tumbleweed' medal haha.
The only solution I could find to this is to comment out the following line:

```
ans <- new("_p_parameters", ref=ans) ;
```

in all function that try to create an R object.
The resulting memory pointer is then assigned to an R object at function call. 
It's dirty, but I couldn't work out how to create an object from a memory pointer (at least from within the functions themselves).
It seems to work so I guess it will do.